# There is an error in Latex: LaTeX Error: Unicode character ： (U+FF1A)

Tags: errors

The compile is good but I get this error :Unicode character ： (U+FF1A)

```
 \documentclass{report}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
 \usepackage{setspace}% for\doublespacing
 \usepackage{indentfirst}% for indent the first line
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{textalpha}
 \usepackage{ragged2e}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
\usepackage{xltabular} 
\begin{document}
The Social interaction (SI) test setup comprised a 42 \texttimes 42 cm Plexiglas arena with a 6.5 \texttimes 10 cm wire mesh cage on one side that allowed for olfactory and minimal tactile interaction. The social interaction zone (SIZ) encompasses a 14 \texttimes 24 cm area projecting 8 cm around the wire-mesh enclosure (Figure A).  The protocol included two trials, one without and one with an unfamiliar CD1 mouse present in the wire mesh enclosure, in this order, both covering 2.5 minutes. The C57BL/6J mouse was placed in the center of this arena, facing the SIZ, and could freely explore the chamber. After 2.5 min, the mouse was removed, and an unfamiliar CD1 mouse was placed in the cage. During this second trial, the C57BL/6J mouse’s reaction to the CD1 mouse was registered. Locomotion and time spent in the SIZ were recorded. The immobility time within the SIZ (indicating potential freezing behavior) was registered to adjust the C57BL/6J mouse’s time interacted with the CD1 mouse. The social interaction ratio (SIR) was calculated as a parameter to indicate social behavior. Variables analyzed within the SI test were locomotion (without a social target) and the social interaction ratio：\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: The character you have after the word `ratio` is not a colon, is a [U+FF1A full-width colon character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+FF1A). Remove it and use a normal colon...

Comment: ：is not the same that : Use : and all will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U+FF1A is `：` full width colon designed for Asian scripts, replace it by `:` a standard colon.

ie replace `social interaction ratio：` by `social interaction ratio:`

Comment: Thank you, this is solved perfectly. The : looks the same, but under different input mode.